# ASP.NET - Encrypt file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, encryption

I am doing a task using ASP.NET where a user must upload a file and I encrypted with an already done encryption algorithm. The properties of the file are: `ID`, `Name`, and `tags`. Now, before I have encrypted strings, like a name for example, however, I've never encrypted a file and have no clue about it.

**What exactly do I have to encrypt?**

**Encryption algorithm:**

```
public static void HybridEncrypt(string publicKey, MemoryStream fileToEncrypt, string filenameOfTheOutputFile)
{
     var publicKeyPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "\\publickey.key");
     Rijndael myAlg = Rijndael.Create();
     myAlg.GenerateIV(); //this is another method how to generate the secret key and iv
     myAlg.GenerateKey();

     byte[] keyStream = myAlg.Key;
     byte[] IVstream = myAlg.Key;
     MemoryStream msFileDataEncrypted = SymmetricEncryptData(fileToEncrypt, keyStream, IVstream);

     MemoryStream keyStreamEncrypt = new MemoryStream(myAlg.Key);
     MemoryStream msEncryptedSecretKey = new Encryption().AsymmetricallyEncrypt(publicKeyPath, keyStreamEncrypt);

     MemoryStream IVStreamEncrypt = new MemoryStream(myAlg.IV);
     MemoryStream msEncryptedIV = new Encryption().AsymmetricallyEncrypt(publicKeyPath, IVStreamEncrypt);

     MemoryStream msAll = new MemoryStream();

     msEncryptedSecretKey.Position = 0;
     msEncryptedIV.Position = 0;
     msFileDataEncrypted.Position = 0;

     msEncryptedSecretKey.CopyTo(msAll);
     msEncryptedIV.CopyTo(msAll);
     msFileDataEncrypted.CopyTo(msAll);
     System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filenameOfTheOutputFile, msAll.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here? How to solve the exception or "what should I encrypt?". Please focus on one question at a time, it makes it easier to provide worthwhile and concrete answers.

Comment: do you have a tipo in `byte[] IVstream = myAlg.Key;` ? It should be `byte[] IVstream = myAlg.IV;` I suppose

Comment: ok so I deleted the error that I had.. My actual problem is what exactly do I encrypt to encrypt a file? Like for example, if I have a table person and I want to encrypt the name, I encrypt the field firstName.. Now if I want to encrypt a file, what do I encrypt?

Comment: Actually you are not encrypting field values or files. You are encrypting byte array. `MemoryStream fileToEncrypt` in your sample is just a wrapper that can supply set of bytes to be encrypted. So it looks like 1) get bytes (stream whatever) 2) encrypt those bytes. Here are [the sample](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f8fa6c/data-encryption-and-decryption-in-C-Sharp/) that converts string to bytes before encryption (just not to be confused with streams). Here is the [AES encryption guide](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/aes-encryption-in-c-sharp/)

Comment: thanks for the reply.. I managed to fix it.. thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 things you need to resolve

1. According to oleksa's comment, you need to correct from `byte[] IVstream = myAlg.Key;` to `byte[] IVstream = myAlg.IV;`
2. You should encrypt file by converting from `httppostedfilebase to memorystream c#` then pass as `fileToEncrypt` param instead of `Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(stringvale)`
3. `ID, Name, and tags` just the information that you store in database, no need to encrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, your initial vector size is less than 16 bytes. You need to increase the initial vector size.